# Create WPF DataTemplate depending on a class attribute concrete type (not class type)

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I'm working with the following classes:

```
public class ConcreteClassFoo
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConcreteComponent> Components { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteComponent
{
    IAttribute Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteAttribute1 : IAttribute {}
public class ConcreteAttribute2 : IAttribute {}
```

Mapped in my XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Bindings Components} />
```

As you can see, my `ListBox` binds the `Components` attribute as `ItemsSource`.

The `Components` attribute is a collection of `ConcreteComponent` that **HAS-A** attribute `Foo` of abstract type `IAttribute`.

I'd like to change the `ListView` template depending on the concrete class of my attribute `Foo`.

With `DataTemplate` it is possible to Build different template depending on the class concrete type, for example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ConcreteComponent1}" />
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ConcreteComponent2}" />
```

But how can be possible to build different template depending on a concrete class **attribute type**?

**UPDATE**:

I add some more infos about my practical problem.

I have a `ListView` containing a `ObservableCollection<BaseWindowShape>` called `Shapes`. The object `BaseWindowShape` has a attribute `AdditionalData` (`AdditionalData` is abstract) that can be a either a `DistanceAdditionalData` or `TermoAdditionalData`.

I'd like to change che `ListView` view depending on the `AdditionalData` concrete type (all the `BaseWindowShape` in the `ListView` share the same concrete `AdditionalData`).

So if the `AdditionalData` of the first shape, for example, is `DistanceAtdditionalData` I'd like to have three column

[image: DistanceAdditionalData]

Otherwise I'd like to have only two column

[image: TermoAdditionalData]

`MaxDistance` and `MinAreaPercent` are `DistanceAdditionalData` attributes, while `MaxTemperature` is a `TermoAdditionalData` attribute.

I try to implement this behaviour in the following way, but it does not work.

How could I solve my problem?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
  <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type additionalData:TridimensionalAdditionalData}">
            <ListView>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Level">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <wpfControls:DigitInput Value="{Binding Level, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Max Distance">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <xctk:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding MaxDistance}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="mm">
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Min Area">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <xctk:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding MinAreaPercent}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type additionalData:ThermalAdditionalData}">
            <ListView>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Level">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <wpfControls:DigitInput Value="{Binding Level, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Max Temperature">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <xctk:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding MaxTemperature}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text=" °F"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding AdditionalData}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**UPDATE 2**:
I update my implementation using **lokusking** answer, here it is:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstComponent}">
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConcreteAttribute1}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Components}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="1 column">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="2 column">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Foo.Number, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConcreteAttribute2}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Components}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="3 column">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="4 column">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Foo.B, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Foo}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I added a property called `FirstComponent` declared as:

```
public ObservableCollection<ConcreteComponent> FirstComponent { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ConcreteComponent> { Components.First() };
```

and bind it as `ItemsSource` of my first `ListView`.
As `DataTemplate` for the `FirstComponent` I declared another `ListView`, binded to the collection `Components` in order to **have different columns depending on it**.
If the first element of my collection has an attribute of `ConcreteAttribute1` I have the following result:

[image]

otherwise the following one:

[image]

Probably it is not the best way to achieve this result (I have to declare a `ObservableCollection` of only one element in order to check it) but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i dont really get what you want to achieve, i can only guess, that this is what you want to do:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ConcreteAttribute1}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Con1"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ConcreteAttribute2}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Con2"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Foo}"></ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

If this doesn't solve your question, please explain yourself a little more

**EDIT**

Here my Demo-Implementation and the result:

**Classes**

```
public class ConcreteComponent {
    public IAttribute Foo {
      get; set;
    }
  }

  public class ConcreteAttribute1 : IAttribute {
    public string Name => "ConAtt 1";
    public int Number => 999;

  }
  public class ConcreteAttribute2 : IAttribute {
    public string Name => "ConAtt 2";
    public bool B => true;

  }

  public interface IAttribute {
    string Name {
      get;
    }
  }
```

**XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ConcreteAttribute1}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Number, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ConcreteAttribute2}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding B, Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Foo}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Usage**

```
public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Components = new ObservableCollection<ConcreteComponent>();
      this.Components.Add(new ConcreteComponent { Foo = new ConcreteAttribute1() });

      this.Components.Add(new ConcreteComponent { Foo = new ConcreteAttribute2() });


      this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ConcreteComponent> Components {
      get;
    }
```

**Result**

[image: ExampleResult]

**Note**

Make sure you dont have typos.
If it's still not working, maybe post screen of wrong Output and/or Exception

Comment: I think it is very near to solve my problem. I update my question adding some more infos and my (wrong) implementation following your answer, tell me if everything is clear now and if you can give me some advice so solve my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: @Rowandish Updated Post

Comment: @lokuskinig It works perfectly, Thanks! In order to solve my practical problem I create a ListView inside another using the first element of the collection in order to decide which kind of columns create  (see my second update); I don't think it is the best way to solve but actually it works. If you have a more elegant way to achieve the same result it would be great!

Comment: You may find [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) usefull as well in case you want to select template based on something else than Type. For example on value of string property